# 502 errors for all endpoint requests without changing anything

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

We just started having lots of 502 errors out of the blue, without deploying anything new. Somehow 99% of all requests to the endpoints don't get through to appengine (as seen in the appengine log). The service status of google app engine and endpoints seems to be green.
We tried deploying a new endpoints api description and a new appengine version using it, also stopping respective versions.

We can also no longer look at the api explorer.

web requests via the gapi js library return "Error 502 (Server Error)!!1" when trying to initialize and load the "_ah/api/static/proxy.html" page

What could be the problem here? Is there a way to "restart" endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

OK, its just magically started working again after around 50min of downtime. I guess it would still be interesting to know if there is anything we could do in cases like this.